# Changing CSV Export Data from Woocommerce using WC Vendors Pro plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, export-to-csv, hook-woocommerce

Child theme using Woocommerce and WC Vendors Pro plugin to allow sellers to have a store and front end dashboard. In their dashboard they have access to orders, and it displays a table of data of the products they sold. We are not using shipping so the shipped field is irrelevant. I have figured out how to hide the "Shipped" column from the table using this code in my child theme functions.php file:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'wcv_order_table_columns', 'remove_wcv_order_table_columns' ); 
function remove_wcv_order_table_columns( $columns ){ 
    unset( $columns['status'] ); 
    return $columns; 
}
?>
```

The issue is now when I click on Export to CSV, it is exporting the data for that column, but NOT the heading, shifting the headings over.
Example:

```
Order   Customer    Products     Total   Order Date
9999    John Smith  1x CD Album  $4.99   **No**           5/21/19
```

NO is the shipped status, so the heading is gone but the data is there, and date header is now incorrectly over the shipped status column.

I've tried the following code:

```
add_filter( 'wcv_orders_table_rows', 'remove_wcv_orders_table_rows' ); 
function remove_wcv_orders_table_rows( $rows ){ 
    unset( $rows['status'] );  
    return $rows; 
}
```

but this doesn't work. I can send the 2 files to anyone that thinks they can help that I believe control this functionality as I do not want to post it here since its a purchased plugin.